# CTC implementation in Keras error

Tags: ocr, keras, lstm

I am working on image OCR with my own dataset, I have 1000 images of variable length and I want to feed in images in form of patches of 46X1. I have generated patches of my images and my label values are in Urdu text, so I have encoded them as utf-8. I want to implement CTC in the output layer. I have tried to implement CTC following the image_ocr example at github. But I get the following error in my CTC implementation.

> 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Could anyone guide me about my mistakes? Kindly suggest the solution for it.

My code is:

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test =train_test_split(imageList, labelList, test_size=0.3)
X_train_patches = np.array([image.extract_patches_2d(X_train[i], (46, 1))for i in range (700)]).reshape(700,1,1) #(Samples, timesteps,dimensions)
X_test_patches = np.array([image.extract_patches_2d(X_test[i], (46, 1))for i in range (300)]).reshape(300,1,1)


Y_train=np.array([i.encode("utf-8") for i in str(Y_train)])
Label_length=1
input_length=1


####################Loss Function########
def ctc_lambda_func(args):
    y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args
    # the 2 is critical here since the first couple outputs of the RNN
    # tend to be garbage:
    y_pred = y_pred[:, 2:, :]
    return K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)

#Building Model

model =Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(20, input_shape=(None, X_train_patches.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(12)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(LSTM(60, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(40)))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc')([X_train_patches, Y_train, input_length, Label_length])
```

Answer (score 2):

The way CTC is modelled currently in Keras is that you need to implement the loss function as a layer, you did that already (`loss_out`). Your problem is that the inputs you give that layer are not tensors from Theano/TensorFlow but numpy arrays.

To change that one option is to model these values as inputs to your model. This is exactly what the [implementation](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/655f5af/examples/image_ocr.py) does that you copied the code from:

```
labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[img_gen.absolute_max_string_len], dtype='float32')
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
# Keras doesn't currently support loss funcs with extra parameters
# so CTC loss is implemented in a lambda layer
loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length])
```

To make this work you need to ditch the `Sequential` model and use the functional model API, exactly as done in the code linked above.

Comment: I have modified my model accordingly, but now I get this error, 
TypeError: Trying to increment a 1-dimensional subtensor with a 7-dimensional value.
any suggestions?